# Raspberry Pi 2 Crash: Internal error oops preempt smp arm

Tags: crash, kernel, raspberry-pi, syslog, temperature

After 24 Hours i get on the Raspberry Pi 2 Syslogs Messages and after this i must Hard Reset/Reboot the Pi.

```
Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12540.865789] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.177016] Process motion (pid: 3151, stack limit = 0xb90c8238)

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.183009] Stack: (0xb90c9d18 to 0xb90ca000)

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.187356] 9d00:                                                       ba7b5280 b90bcc60

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.195520] 9d20: b90c9d4c b90b0450 b90bcc60 70a90000 00002000 b90c9d88 00000000 b939c700

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.203683] 9d40: b90c9d7c b90c9d50 80112f7c 8011e600 70a90000 00418004 b81e26e0 b90c9db0

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.211847] 9d60: b939c700 b2831ae4 00418004 b9365c00 b90c9dec b90c9d80 8011b5f8 80112f4c

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.220011] 9d80: 805227fc 800cae38 b939c700 00000001 00000000 73dfa000 ffffffff b939c700

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.228174] 9da0: 00000000 00000107 00000400 a0e39000 80522834 b9365c00 00000009 b90c8000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.236337] 9dc0: b2831ae4 b939c700 00000000 b90c8000 b939c700 00000000 b90c8000 b2831ae4

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.244501] 9de0: b90c9e04 b90c9df0 80021b4c 8011b508 b90c8008 b936603c b90c9e54 b90c9e08

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.252664] 9e00: 800264c0 80021b08 b90c9e2c b939c738 00000001 8002e1ec b9365fe8 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.260829] 9e20: b90c9e74 b90c9e30 8002eb74 b2840dc0 00000009 b90c8000 b2831ae4 00418004

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.268993] 9e40: b2831ae0 b90c8038 b90c9e74 b90c9e58 80026c8c 80026210 b90c8000 00000009

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.277156] 9e60: b90c9ed4 b2831ae4 b90c9ebc b90c9e78 80031278 80026c48 b2840dc0 b90c9ec0

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.285319] 9e80: b90c8000 b2831a40 b2831f44 00000020 ba081540 b90c9fb0 00000000 b90c9ec0

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.293483] 9ea0: 00000000 00000000 b90c8000 734d5370 b90c9f84 b90c9ec0 80011c9c 80030ff0

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.301646] 9ec0: b90c9f74 b90c9ed0 8051e484 80045470 b2855640 00000009 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.309809] 9ee0: 00000000 00000000 e41f0173 00000b67 8051e960 807ad540 807ad540 807ad540

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.317973] 9f00: 8006fc34 800cae38 ba081540 b90c8000 b90c8000 00000003 807d4200 b90c8000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.326136] 9f20: b90c9f44 b90c9f30 80027f6c 8006fbb4 807ad540 807ad540 b90c9f6c b90c9f48

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.334300] 9f40: 80049a5c 800148a0 80811f88 b90c8008 b90c8000 00000000 b90c9fb0 b90c8008

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.342463] 9f60: b90c8000 00000000 b90c9fb0 00000000 b90c8000 734d5370 b90c9fac b90c9f88

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.350626] 9f80: 8001218c 80011c10 00000000 00000001 0001f570 20000010 00000003 10c5387d

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.358790] 9fa0: 00000000 b90c9fb0 8000eb18 800120f4 00000014 00000002 001fa400 001a9cd9

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.366953] 9fc0: 00000000 72740008 00000001 73ab9ce2 72cdfce2 00000000 734d5370 73618008

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.375117] 9fe0: 00000000 75022b68 0000e690 0001f570 20000010 ffffffff 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.449516] Code: ea000001 e1a0a005 e1a05002 e59a7004 (e5978000)

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.455602] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#2] PREEMPT SMP ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.567673] Process pdns_server (pid: 3457, stack limit = 0xb2880238)

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.574102] Stack: (0xb2881ea0 to 0xb2882000)

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.578455] 1ea0: 00000875 a0d3c948 b2881f44 b2881eb8 8002315c 8010f014 b93e8fc0 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.586621] 1ec0: a7265268 b2880000 76fe6068 01200011 a0e38904 a0e388f8 b9604970 a0e388f0

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.594787] 1ee0: b82e08f8 b93e8ff8 b2880038 95f5c500 00000000 95f5c754 a0e38900 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.602953] 1f00: 00000000 00000000 2743308d 00000b68 00000001 fffffff4 b2809e18 76fe6068

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.611119] 1f20: 7ec5e460 01200011 00000078 8000ed44 00000000 00000000 b2881f8c b2881f48

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.619285] 1f40: 800234d0 80021e5c 00000000 00000000 76fbd000 8000ed44 b2880000 8011a5fc

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.627450] 1f60: b2881f8c 76fe6068 7ec5e460 00000d81 00000078 8000ed44 b2880000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.635617] 1f80: b2881fa4 b2881f90 800238b0 80023430 76fe6068 800cad0c 00000000 b2881fa8

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.643786] 1fa0: 8000eac0 80023890 76fe6068 7ec5e460 01200011 00000000 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.651959] 1fc0: 76fe6068 7ec5e460 00000d81 00000078 768b1000 00000000 00000003 7ec5e49c

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.660130] 1fe0: 76fe64c0 7ec5e460 00000d81 7681e848 60000010 01200011 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:53 ...
 kernel:[12542.700834] Code: e3530000 e08ce62e 02814030 0a000007 (e593c00c)

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12544.888137] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#3] PREEMPT SMP ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12544.989803] Process mysqld (pid: 3428, stack limit = 0xb2862238)

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12544.995795] Stack: (0xb2863ce8 to 0xb2864000)

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.000145] 3ce0:                   00100073 b960112c b9370d10 b960113c b960112c b2863d88

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.008309] 3d00: b2863d2c b2863d10 80118424 8010eccc b9370d4c b91d1840 b9370d10 b9601150

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.016473] 3d20: b2863d4c b2863d30 80118cf0 8011839c b9370d10 b93703c8 63fd1000 00002000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.024636] 3d40: b2863d7c b2863d50 80112fd0 80118cb8 00000000 00418004 b296e7e8 b2863db0

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.032800] 3d60: b9015340 b904d4a4 00418004 b83ebf40 b2863dec b2863d80 8011b5f8 80112f4c

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.040963] 3d80: b82fea80 00000000 b9015340 00000001 00000000 78949000 ffffffff b9015340

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.049126] 3da0: 00000000 00000011 00000400 b9257000 00000000 00000000 b2863da8 b2863da8

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.057289] 3dc0: b904d4a4 b9015340 00000000 b2862000 b9015340 00000000 b2862000 b904d4a4

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.065453] 3de0: b2863e04 b2863df0 80021b4c 8011b508 b2862008 b83ec37c b2863e54 b2863e08

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.073616] 3e00: 800264c0 80021b08 b2863e2c b9015378 00000001 8002e1ec b83ec328 7662c504

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.081780] 3e20: b2863e74 b2863e30 8002eb74 b800d080 00000009 b2862000 b904d4a4 00418004

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.089943] 3e40: b904d4a0 b2862038 b2863e74 b2863e58 80026c8c 80026210 b2862000 00000009

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.098106] 3e60: b2863ed4 b904d4a4 b2863ebc b2863e78 80031278 80026c48 b800d080 b2863ec0

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.106270] 3e80: b2862000 b904d400 b904d904 00000020 8007621c b2863fb0 7662c504 b2863ec0

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.114433] 3ea0: 7662c508 fffffffc b2862000 00000000 b2863f84 b2863ec0 80011c9c 80030ff0

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.122597] 3ec0: 00000001 fffffe00 b2863f7c b2863ed8 801821c8 00000009 00000000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.130759] 3ee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 b83ebf40 80059d90 b2863ef8 b2863ef8

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.138923] 3f00: b2863f00 00000000 a0c2df08 00000000 e04736d2 00000b67 e0467382 00000b67

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.147086] 3f20: 80075bbc ba061600 00000000 00000d64 00000000 7173796d 7300646c 00656661

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.155249] 3f40: 00000000 00000000 b83ebf40 b2863f58 80181c70 00000001 00000100 b2862008

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.163413] 3f60: b2862000 8000ed44 b2863fb0 8000ed44 b2862000 00000000 b2863fac b2863f88

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.171577] 3f80: 8001218c 80011c10 8000eacc 00000001 69d6dd4c 00000100 783118e0 000000f5

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.179740] 3fa0: 00000000 b2863fb0 8000eb18 800120f4 fffffffc 00000001 00000100 783118e0

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.187904] 3fc0: 69d6dd4c 00000100 783118e0 000000f5 00000200 69d6dd4c 739a5000 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.196067] 3fe0: 69d6dd4c 69d6dd10 76bc73d0 7662c508 20000010 739a5000 3a7fa821 3a7fac21

Message from syslogd@raspberry at Mar 20 23:30:56 ...
 kernel:[12545.289050] Code: 1a000002 ea00007f e1a0e003 e1a03002 (e5932008)
```

I hope ... one can help me.  :)

**Update:** Fix be change overclocking lower, because the temperature is to hot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you've not got a "pi 1" type overclocking set (sudo raspi-config). (That was my problem after upgrading hardware from pi 1).

Comment: The Overclocking Making Problems, because it was to hot. :D