# Can't understand why node process is crashing on raspberry pi 2

Tags: linux, node.js, express, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi

I have created a node program which uses selenium web driver and cycles through URLs.

However I'm not closing the web driver instance.

The program is running on a raspberry pi 2 for 4 to 5 hours and then crashes.

It freezes the pi. I'm getting an error as PREEMPT ARM. Someother info related to stack.

I'm not sure if this is a memory leak with the program because i'm not closing the web driver instance or the limitation of resources on the pi itself.

Comment: Check the syslog. One of your processes is probably killed by the OOM-killer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your pi is getting to hot.
Check the error message here 
[Raspberry Pi 2 Crash: Internal error oops preempt smp arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178044/raspberry-pi-2-crash-internal-error-oops-preempt-smp-arm)

The default clock setting is unstable on some devices. Take a look here
how to change the clock settings.
[a-look-at-raspberry-pi-2-performance](http://linuxonflash.blogspot.co.at/2015/02/a-look-at-raspberry-pi-2-performance.html)