# Raspberry Pi 2: Crashes with kernel error PREEMPT SMP ARM

Tags: kernel, syslog, raspberry-pi2

My Raspberry Pi 2 was running for half hour and crashed with the following message:

```
Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Oct 27 22:23:56 ...
 kernel:[ 9330.745037] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Oct 27 22:23:56 ...
 kernel:[ 9330.833248] Process kworker/0:1 (pid: 43, stack limit = 0xb9b3e238)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Oct 27 22:23:56 ...
 kernel:[ 9330.839507] Stack: (0xb9b3fc90 to 0xb9b40000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Oct 27 22:23:56 ...
 kernel:[ 9330.843863] fc80:                                     b8621000 b86218b8 00000674 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Oct 27 22:23:56 ...
 kernel:[ 9330.852036] fca0: b9b3fcf4 b9b3fcb0 7f02dccc 7f032e20 b861a130 b861a11c b8621008 b8621028
```

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178044/raspberry-pi-2-crash-internal-error-oops-preempt-smp-arm) has an answer but I didn't quite understand the proposed solution. What exactly needs to be changed in raspi-config? Any pointers would be helpful.